# How can call webapi(file upload) from .net core application

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-webapi

[image: code part 1]
[image: code part 2]

i want to consume Api from .net core application,but when i send file image along with data not do that

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! 
People will have a way easier time helping you if you provide the code as code directly in the question. 
Looking at an image is really uneasy.

Comment: "when i send file image along with data not do that" What's error message do you get?